# jQuery for finding next page button in the page

Tags: jquery, web-crawler

I want to locate the 'next button'  tag on a web page.
I have been struggling to figure it out for a day but failed.

There are some restrictions on this problem:

1. Need to find a single query which can be used with $() API. (cannot
   use traversal method like parent and siblings)
2. With the same query, I have to find '10 more pages' button element.

Can anyone help me find this?

From the following code for pagination, I need to locate  tag for page #2 (current class indicates the current page)

```
<div id="pagination"
  class="part page"
  data-bind="html: renderPagination(), visible: !!normalSearchResults().sr.length"> <span class="page"><a href="javascript:;" class="current" data-page="1">1</a></span> <span class="page"><a href="javascript:;"  data-page="2">2</a></span>  <span class="page"><a href="javascript:;" class="" data-page="3">3</a></span> <span class="page"><a href="javascript:;" class="" data-page="4">4</a></span>  <span class="page"><a href="javascript:;" class="" data-page="5">5</a></span> <span class="page"><a href="javascript:;" class="" data-page="6">6</a></span>  <span class="page"><a href="javascript:;" class="" data-page="7">7</a></span> <span class="page"><a href="javascript:;" class="" data-page="8">8</a></span>  <span class="page"><a href="javascript:;" class="" data-page="9">9</a></span> <span class="page"><a href="javascript:;" class="" data-page="10">10</a></span>
  <span
  class="next">
    <a href="javascript:;"
      data-page="11"><img src="/images/common/list/btn_list_next.gif"
        alt="next 10 pages"></a>
    </span><span class="moveTop"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="jQuery(window).scrollTop(0);">to the top</a></span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could select thoses html tags:

```
// Get current data-page, then add + 1 and select by data-page value html tag
console.log( $(`#pagination [data-page=${parseInt($("#pagination [className='current']").attr('data-page')) + 1}]`)[0]);

// Next ten link : Get next ten page anchor hmtl tag
console.log( $("[className='next']").find('a')[0]);
```

I you want to have this in a single object you could do that:

```
const tags = {
    next: $(`#pagination [data-page=${parseInt($("#pagination [className='current']").attr('data-page')) + 1}]`)[0],
    nextTen: $("#pagination [className='next']").find('a')[0]
}

console.log(tags);
```

I don't understand what you mean by "i want to locate this tag". Do you want to locate tags on the screen ?

```
console.log(tags.next.getBoundingClientRect())
console.log(tags.nextTen.getBoundingClientRect())
```

This will return the position of the tags in the viewport.

Comment: Actually i'm trying to crawl this web site with a chrome extension (data-miner.io)

http://www.encar.com/dc/dc_carsearchlist.do?carType=kor#!%7B%22action%22%3A%22(And.Hidden.N._.(C.CarType.Y._.(C.Manufacturer.%EA%B8%B0%EC%95%84._.ModelGroup.%EB%AA%A8%EB%8B%9D.)))%22%7D

And the crawler extension doesn't allow me to use javascript inside query. (like ${1+2})

parseInt function didn't work in the extension. Thank you about the suggestion though.

Comment: Ok I see. Maybe it could be easier to use Python and a lib like scrappy to achieve what you want: https://scrapy.org/. Also there's not restriction here ( like call or page limits / month )